# Why aren't class methods available here with module ClassMethod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Ruby 2.6.3 ; Rails 6.0.3

I've got a module and a class including it but I cannot make any class methods available on the class, only instance methods

```rb
module Importable
  def self.inlcuded(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods

    base.class_eval do
      scope :from_source_a, -> { where(import_source: "source_a") }
    end
  end

  def from_source_a?
    self.import_source == "source_a"
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def find_from_source_a(id)
      self.find_by(
        import_source: "source_a",
        import_id: id
      )
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  include Importable
end
```

so

`Employee.first.from_source_a?` works
but
`Employee.find_from_source_a(id)` throws a `NoMethodError: undefined method find_from_source_a for Employee`

But examples I'm looking at make it look like this should work. Any thoughts on what I'm getting wrong here?

Comment: If you're using Rails, why not use [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you made a typo.

`self.included(base)` not `self.inlcuded(base)`